# Changing page location after google analytics setup

Tags: web, google-analytics, analytics

The current website structure is setup such that all the ASPX pages are in the main folder. It's becoming increasingly difficult to maintain, so I would like to create new folders and move the relevant pages. This would change the URL from say:

http://mydomain.com/DoStuff.aspx

to

http://mydomain.com/DoingFolder/DoStuff.aspx

I fear that this will skew up the google analytics results. Is it recommended I do this change? If so, is there a way to link the page locations of after and before the change?

Also, what would happen when I implement the URL rewrite? Would I run into the same issue again? Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in general I think it is a good idea to add the folder for both your users to visually see the section they are in via the URL and to help the search engines figure out the areas and who knows you may even get a (small) SEO benefit out of it.

What I would advise is to setup a second profile in Analytics and then add a filter which removes the folder name from the request and will leave you with the same flat structure in your reports as you have currently.  (NB Do this under a new profile with the same tracking code to avoid major mess-ups that you can't undo).

Cheers

Z